# Listing Post Ids within loop on page?

Tags: wordpress, post, loops

Is there anyway to list the post IDs for all the posts in the loop on a page in Wordpress?

Id like to make a navigation bar out of the current posts on the page.

Wordpress 3.3

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) to get all posts and loop through it for ids, example:

```
<?php

// The Query
query_posts( $args );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
echo '<li>';
the_title();
echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();

?>
```